# Cannot process definition to array for type time in Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, upgrade, magento2.3.3

I'm getting the following error "Cannot process definition to array for type time" on Magento 2.3.3 when executing command:
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Thank you for your advanced!

Comment: Please post your custom script?

Comment: Hi @KhoaTruongDinh I try to run this command line: php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: From a fresh Magento install?

Comment: No, I have installed some extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `time` in your setup script then use the `timestamp` , `datetime` OR `date` instead of `time`

Comment: Do you know why I should use timestamp, datetime or date instead time?

Comment: Yes, because `time` type is not defined in Magento, so that's why you should use timestamp , datetime OR date instead of time

Comment: @DavidDuong If you can post your script then i can fix issue in that script

Comment: Great job! Thanks you! I have found table magesms_birthdaymessages_template in file app/code/Topefekt/Magesms/Setup/InstallSchema.php have used time.